# Connection refused on heroku using generator-sql-fullstack

Tags: angularjs, node.js, heroku, sequelize.js, yeoman-generator-angular

you are my last chance here. So I've build a project with generator-sql-fullstack package and trying to deploy it to heroku.

Unfortunately, I can't connect to Heroku database as I get Error R10.
I've tried different ways to connect to postgres through sequelize - none of them worked. The main thing was to make it ssl compatible, but it still doesn't connect (or maybe I am using it wrong)

Project runs great locally, app is build without any errors also.

Please, take a look into Heroku logs and main files for connection. Hopefully, you will be able to help me here. Thank you.

```
$ heroku logs
2016-04-18T21:27:36.994697+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server/app.js
2016-04-18T21:27:36.994705+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-04-18T21:27:37.784886+00:00 app[web.1]: Express server listening on 55648, in production mode
2016-04-18T21:28:34.891786+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2016-04-18T21:28:34.891786+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2016-04-18T21:28:35.750471+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
```

/server/config/environment/production.js

```
module.exports = {
  database: 'DBNAME',
  username: 'DBUSERNAME',
  password: 'DBPASSWORD',
  sql: {
      host: 'DBHOST',
      port: process.env.PORT || '5432',
      dialect: 'postgres',
       dialectOptions: {
        ssl: true
      }
    }
};
```

/server/api/index.js

```
var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config.sql);
```

Other than that, nothing was touched on server side.
My guess is that I am using Sequelize incorrectly, but I followed documentation (to adapt SSL for heroku).

Please, let me know if you want to see more configuration files.

Thank you for any input!

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
var sequelize =  new Sequelize(process.env.DATABASE_URL);
```

should be enough for connecting to Heroku's Postgres. You can check that DATABASE_URL in Heroku Dashboard -> YourApp -> Settings -> Config Variables. You can also take db credentials from that string, but you don't need to.

process.env.PORT is not the database port, but port on which you should start your server(so Heroku can do its internal routing things), like:

```
server.listen(process.env.PORT || 5432)
```

So you config file should look something like:

```
module.exports = {
 port: process.env.PORT || 5432,
 database: {
  uri: process.env.DATABASE_URL
 }
};
```

And connecting to database with:

```
var sequelize =  new Sequelize(config.database.uri);
```

Comment: Yes, I've tried that.. Same issue. Is there any way to debug connection manually? I am so frustrated..

Comment: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch - this is not Sequelize or Postgres issue.

But you can connect to your database with any pg db manager, or with heroku cli: heroku pg:psql --app yourappname DATABASE